GameKit/GameCenter invitation process gets stuck on “Retrieving” when using iMessage invite link
I’m working on an iOS app that uses GameKit/GameCenter to invite friends to play. However, when a friend tries to press the invite link sent via iMessage, it shows “Retrieving” briefly and then disappears, without redirecting to my app.
I’m not sure what I’m missing or doing wrong.
Here’s what I’ve implemented:
I’m using the following code to handle match invitations:
import Foundation
import GameKit

extension RealTimeGame: GKLocalPlayerListener {
    /// Handles when the local player sends requests to start a match with other players.
    func player(_ player: GKPlayer, didRequestMatchWithRecipients recipientPlayers: [GKPlayer]) {
        print("\n\nSending invites to other players.")
    }

    /// Presents the matchmaker interface when the local player accepts an invitation from another player.
    func player(_ player: GKPlayer, didAccept invite: GKInvite) {
        // Present the matchmaker view controller in the invitation state.
        if let viewController = GKMatchmakerViewController(invite: invite) {
            viewController.matchmakerDelegate = self
            rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true) { }
        }
    }
}

What I’ve tried:
•   I’ve reviewed the GameKit documentation but couldn’t find specific details about handling iMessage invitations.
•   I’m unsure if I need to add <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key> to my Info.plist. I haven’t added it yet because I’m not certain it’s required for this functionality.
•   I’ve looked through several forums and Stack Overflow questions but haven’t found a solution that addresses this issue specifically.

Expected behavior:
•   The app should handle the invite link properly, allowing the user to accept the invitation and be redirected to the app to start the game.

Actual behavior:
•   The iMessage invite link shows “Retrieving” and then disappears without redirecting the user to my app.

Thank you for any insights or suggestions!
